# How to create a border around circle which is created using drawrect method in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawrect

Hi in one of my application i had created a circle using drawrect method on UIView object.Now my concern i want draw a highlight border around the circle for that actually i used

```
 myView.layer.borderWidth =3.0;

 myView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:myView.patternRed green:myView.patternGreen   blue:myView.patternBlue alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

But due to this code what is happening is a border is creating around the view and it's looks a rectangle, but i want to create a border around the circle itself. So if anyone know how to implement this functionality please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set some radius for the corners of that view so add this line

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius=20;
```

play with the numeric value to match your requirements

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 80.0f;
```

It'll curve your view into a circle.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi iManan thanks a lot for your reply.i Tried the thing what you mentioned it is work it out for few circles not for all because the dimesions of the circle are dynamic. For example:  if the width and height of the circle are 150, 150 then cornerradius =65.0f is fine . If i change the width and height to 200,200 then the cornet radius 65.0f is not suitable i have to chnage the corner radius again dynamically. So can you please let me know the formula for chnaging the corner radius based on width and height of the circle dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this : myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES; & myView.layer.opaque = NO; -- This may be hep you.

Comment: Hi i tried but no use. My requirement the changes the corner radius of the view based on circle width and height.

Answer (score 0):

```
This Works for me:

UIView *myView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[self createRoundUIView:myView:80];

-(void)createRoundUIView:(UIView *)inputView sizeDiameter:(float)diameterSize;
{
    CGPoint saveCenter = inputView.center;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(inputView.frame.origin.x, inputView.frame.origin.y, diameterSize, diameterSize);
    roundedView.frame = frame;
    roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = diameterSize / 2.0;
    roundedView.center = saveCenter;
}
```